# Python - Sudoku puzzle generator with Backtracking method

Tags: python, backtracking, sudoku

I'm writing a code for generating a Sudoku puzzle, but some error is there. I've used the [Backtracking method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku_solving_algorithms#Backtracking).

I have used def for checking row, column and individual grids which works alright; I've checked them individually.
I've started placing numbers from the beginning with random numbers, and if and when they don't satisfy the checks, they enter a while loop with three conditions until the conditions are satisfied.
Here's the code:

```
from random import choice

a = [['-','-','-', '-','-','-', '-','-','-'],\
     ['-','-','-', '-','-','-', '-','-','-'],\
     ['-','-','-', '-','-','-', '-','-','-'],\

     ['-','-','-', '-','-','-', '-','-','-'],\
     ['-','-','-', '-','-','-', '-','-','-'],\
     ['-','-','-', '-','-','-', '-','-','-'],\

     ['-','-','-', '-','-','-', '-','-','-'],\
     ['-','-','-', '-','-','-', '-','-','-'],\
     ['-','-','-', '-','-','-', '-','-','-']]

def sudoku_board():
    #returns the sudoku board the way it's supposed to look
    board = ''
    for i in range(9):
        if i==3 or i==6: board+='\n\n'
        else: board += '\n'
        for j in range(9):
            if j==2 or j==5: board += str(a[i][j]) + '\t'
            else: board+= str(a[i][j]) + ' '
    return board

def col_check(x,y,num):
    #checks whether the elements from a column repeat or not
    #returns True if elements repeat, False otherwise
    col = 0
    for m in range(9):
        if a[m][y] == str(num):
            col = 1
            break
    return col
    
def row_check(x,y,num):
    #checks whether the elements from a row repeat or not
    #returns True if elements repeat, False otherwise
    row = 0
    for m in range(9):
        if m!=y and a[x][m] == str(num):
            row = 1
            break
    return row
    
def grid_check(x,y,num):
    #checks whether the elements from a grid repeat or not
    #returns True if elements repeat, False otherwise
    grid = 0
    for m in [(x//3),(x//3)+1,(x//3)+2]:
        for n in [(y//3),(y//3)+1,(y//3)+2]:
            if a[m][n] == str(num):
                grid = 1
                break
    return grid

i,j = 0,0
while i!=8 and j!=8:
    num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    rand_num = choice(num)
    c=0
    while col_check(i,j,rand_num)==1 or row_check(i,j,rand_num)==1 or grid_check(i,j,rand_num)==1:
        if c<9:
            c+=1
            num.remove(rand_num)
            rand_num = choice(num)
        else:
            c=0
            num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
            if j==True: j-=1
            else: i-=1
    a[i][j]=str(rand_num)
    if j==8:
        j=0
        if i!=8: i+=1
        else: break
    else: j+=1
    
print(sudoku_board())
```

After running, I find the cells filled till row,col = 0,7. The loop seems to terminate after that. Can't find the error though I'm pretty sure it's in between line 73-77.
Can anyone tell me what's wrong, thanks!

Comment: One thing I see is that the grid check doesn't check if it compares a cell with itself.

Comment: I couldn't understand, can you elaborate?

Comment: E. g. in `row_check` there is `m!=y` but nothing similar in `grid_check`.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I actually thought it wasn't necessary cuz it's never gonna return True, right.. And I left the other check as it is. Both are no harm, right?